# What apps allow me to draw on an iPad and sync it with a Mac?

Tags: ios, applications, drawing

I am wondering whether there is an app that allows me to draw on an iPad and sync it with a Mac. I think doing so is helpful because I can switch between PowerPoint slides and the canvas and do some drawing.

A scenario I can imagine is that I am talking on Zoom and sharing my slides with my audience. Then I want to write on a blackboard to explain a concept with some drawing. I want to be able to switch to an app on Mac that is synced with the canvas on my iPad so that I can write on the iPad while the students can see my shared screen and writing in real-time through Zoom.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Are you thinking on live drawing during a presentation?

Comment: OneNote does this in almost real time, but your question is lacking in key details so I’m not sure if it’ll fit your needs.  Consider adding some more details about what exactly you’re looking for.

Comment: [Here are site guidelines for a productive software recommendation question.](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation) If yours gets down votes or closed - an edit could make it more likely to get answers. If someone has an answer of course, they are free to put one up but I would need some details to offer anything other than say  use PowerPoint on both since they allow markup and drawing.

Answer (score 1):

In the iPad User Guide, see the section titled “Use iPad as a second display for your Mac”
[image]
Excerpt From
iPad User Guide
Apple Inc.
https://books.apple.com/us/book/ipad-user-guide/id1464778568
This material may be protected by copyright.

Comment: How would this work in the context given by the OP?

Comment: When the iPad and Mac are mirrored, the same thing is seen on both.